# download xls file from a webpage, web scraper

Tags: web, web-scraping, download, xls

I am new to python world and I want to do web scraping.

I want to download some xls documents from the following website to a specific location folder. (eg desktop)

Could you please help me with this ?

The website is

https://www.ici.org/research/stats

I have tried codes available to similar questions but I didnt manage to make them work for my case :(

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use BeautifulSoup, you first need to understand how html source code is structured. You can find some basic tutorials on that by a simple google search.

But the very basic is that html code contains elements with `tags` and those tags have `attributes`. The things you are looking for are under the `<a>` tags, with the the corresponding link as the `href` attribute. So we need to find all the `<a>` tags, that have an `href` attribute that has the excel extension `xls`.

You can see this by inspecting the page (right click on the page and select Inspect, or ctrl-shift-I, to open up the dev tools pane. You can then click around to find the parts you need with the corresponding html code) and viewing the html source:

[image]

Once you have those, you'll iterate through them to open, and save. We will also only do it for ones where "Supplement: Worldwide Public Tables" is in the text/content for that tagged element.

Just make sure to choose the correct root directory where you want it saved where it says `output = open('C:/path/to/desktop/' + filename, 'wb')`:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


desktop = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

url = 'https://www.ici.org/research/stats'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
excel_files = soup.select('a[href*=xls]')

for each in excel_files:
    if 'Supplement: Worldwide Public Tables' in each.text:
        link = 'https://www.ici.org' + each['href']

        filename = each['href'].split('/')[-1]

        if os.path.isfile(desktop + '/' + filename):
            print ('*** File already exists: %s ***' %filename)
            continue

        resp = requests.get(link)
        output = open(desktop + '/' + filename, 'wb')
        output.write(resp.content)
        output.close()
        print ('Saved: %s' %filename)
```

Comment: thank you for the help, could you please tell me how I can incorporate to download a document which contain smth on the tile? (eg I want to download only the docs that include on their name "Supplement: Worldwide Public Tables," .Also could you please tell me a bit more for the href? I really do not understand what needs to be in. Apologies if my question is really stupid but I am really new to this world :)

Comment: how yould you amend the code you included above if you wanted to download the thrww documents that contain the Supplement: Worldwide Public Tables," in their names? Lets say I want to download it to my desktop. Also, what are the <a> tags you menationed above? I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Dimitra I editted/added info to the solution for you

Comment: Hi  chitown88! Thank you for being here and helping!  :) So  now it downloads the documents with these names? I have tried the code above and asked to save them in my desktop and I cannot see them, could you please tell me how this works? Do i need to include anything ? Many any thanks :)

Comment: thanks a lot it works! :) is there a chanc to incorporate an if function that will check whether the each excel doc is already saved in my folder?

Comment: Thank you  chitown88 its amazing work :) I guess I can amend the excel_files = soup.select('a[href*=xls]') to pdf if I want to download a pdf document from a website correct? I want to expand and and download a few pdfs from various website :)

Comment: Hi @chitown88! I am wondering how we can modify the code below to download a factsheet from the website:https://am.jpmorgan.com/gb/en/asset-management/gim/liq/products/d/jpm-euro-liquidity-a-acc-lu0070177232. I want to download the Factsheet that is available there

Comment: @Dimitra , do you mean the fund facts table? I don’t see anything to download (although I’m viewing it from my phone). Actually shoot me an email, we can just take this offline. Jason.schvach@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you @chitown88 for offering your help. I will drop you an email explaining in detail the end goal. :) many thanks again